# concatenate strings of one column separated by comma in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I would like to concatenate string with double quotes which is in a column followed by comma as I would like import this to an SQL query.

```
   A<-c('John', 'Kate', 'Kaitlyn', 'Arun',' Chen')
   df<- data.frame(A)
```

So I would like to concatenate all the rows of A and get a string from this column A and would like to get the output as text file. Below is the expected text. Any suggestions?

```
        "John", "Kate", "Kaitlyn", "Arun", "Chen"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
#Data
A<-c('John', 'Kate', 'Kaitlyn', 'Arun',' Chen')
df<- data.frame(A,stringsAsFactors = F)
df$A <- paste0('\"',trimws(df$A),'\"')
#Collapse
df2 <- data.frame(val=paste0(df$A,collapse = ', '),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Export
write.table(df2,file='File.txt',row.names = F,col.names = F,quote = F)
```

Output:

[image]